# writing a c++ program that takes a string and returns number of palindromes and longest palindrome

Tags: c++, string, split, counting, palindrome

I have to write a program that takes a string as input and outputs the number of words in the string, number of palindromes, and the longest palindrome. I have got a decent start with iterating through the string and returning how many words there and I have an idea of how to iterate through those words to find the palindrome but I am pretty stuck right now. This is what I have right now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
    std::string word = "";
    std::string words;
    std::getline(std::cin, words);
    int word_count = 1;
    int palindrome_count = 0;
    for (auto check : words) {
        if (check == ' ') {
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                if (word[i] == word[word.length() - 1 - i]) {
                    palindrome_count++;
                }
            }
            word = "";
            word_count++;
        }
        else {
            word = word + check;
        }
    }
    std::cout << word_count << " words" << std::endl;
    std::cout << palindrome_count << " palindromes" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Do you need to check each word in the string whether it is a palindrome?

Comment: Recommendation: Make a function called `is_palidrome` that takes a string and returns a boolean, true if the string is a palindrome and false if not. This allows you to split up your logic better. Smaller functions with fewer responsibilities are almost always easier to get working and verify. Now all you should have to do is break the string into words (`std::istringstream` is good at this) and pass each word into `is_palindrome`. If yes, count it and see if it's bigger than the biggest palindrome you've seen so far.

Comment: yes I do need to check every word in the string to see if it is a palindrome

Answer (score 0):

We, beginners, should help each other.:)

Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::string s;
    
    std::cout << "Enter a text: ";

    std::getline( std::cin, s );
    
    size_t total_words = 0;
    size_t palindrome_words = 0;
    std::string max_palindrome;
    
    std::istringstream is( s );
    std::string word;
    
    while ( is >> word )
    {
        ++total_words;
        if ( std::equal( std::begin( word ), std::end( word ), 
                         std::rbegin( word ), std::rend( word ) ) )
        {
            ++palindrome_words;
            
            if ( max_palindrome.size() < word.size() )
            {
                max_palindrome = word;
            }
        }                        
    }
    
    std::cout << "There are " << total_words << " in the entered text.\n";
    std::cout << "Among them there are " << palindrome_words << " palindromes.\n";
    
    if ( palindrome_words != 0 )
    {
        std::cout << "The maximum palindrome is " << max_palindrome << '\n';
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a text: 12 123 1232 12321 121 21
There are 6 in the entered text.
Among them there are 2 palindromes.
The maximum palindrome is 12321
```

The check for a palindrome can be made more efficient the way shown in the answer of **@Ted Lyngmo**. That is the if statement in the program above can be written like

```
if ( std::equal( std::begin( word ), 
                 std::next( std::begin( word ), word.size() / 2 ), 
                 std::rbegin( word ) ) )
```

As for your approach then it is incorrect. For example there can be more than one blank between words. So this if statement

```
  if (check == ' ') {
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
      if (word[i] == word[word.length() - 1 - i]) {
        palindrome_count++;
      }
    }
    word = "";
    word_count ++;
  }
```

will produce wrong results. Also this if statement

```
      if (word[i] == word[word.length() - 1 - i]) {
        palindrome_count++;
      }
```

within the for loop increases the variable `palindrome_count` for each two letters equal each other though the whole word is not a palindrome.

Comment: hello thank you for the help! This code works perfectly but the only thing is it only processes one line of input. I need to be able to take more than one line of input and the only way I can think to do that would be to call get line as a loop condition but I can't figure out how to get that to work. Any ideas?

Comment: @gobygonagle Use one more loop. For example while ( std::getline( std::cin, s ) && s[0] != '\n' ) { /* ... */ }

Answer (score 0):

I would take the `string` that you've read into `words` and put it in a [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream). This simplifies extracting word by word.

```
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    // ...

    std::istringstream is(words);
    std::string word;

    while(is >> word) {
        // ...
    }
```

You now get one word at a time in `word`.

Checking if it's a palindrome can be done by searching `word` from both ends and comparing letters until the algorithm meets in the middle. If any letter doesn't match on the way to the middle, it's not a palindrome.

```
bool is_palindrome(const std::string& word) {
    auto b = word.begin();
    auto e = word.end();  // points to one char after the last letter
    for(;b < e; ++b) {
        if(*b != *--e) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Or using a standard algorithm, [`std::equal`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal):

```
#include <algorithm>
bool is_palindrome(const std::string& s) {
    return std::equal(s.begin(), s.begin() + s.size()/2, s.rbegin());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what should count as a delimiters (I guess you want to ignore punctuations too) but here's my attempt:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

bool isPalindrome(std::string_view word)
{
    size_t idxLeft{0}, idxRight{word.size()-1};
    while (idxLeft < idxRight) {
        if(word[idxLeft] != word[idxRight]) return false;
        idxLeft++, idxRight--;
    }
    return true;
}

std::vector<std::string> split(std::string_view text)
{
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    std::string_view::const_iterator itPrev = begin(text);
    while (itPrev != end(text)) {
        auto itBegin = std::find_if(itPrev, end(text), [](char c){ return std::isalnum(c); });
        auto itEnd = std::find_if(itBegin, end(text), [](char c){ return !std::isalnum(c); });
        if (itBegin == itEnd) break;
        words.emplace_back(itBegin, itEnd);
        itPrev = itEnd;
    }
    return words;
}

int main()
{
    std::string text = "redivider, one, two, deified, civic, three, radar, level, four, five, rotor, kayak, six, reviver, seven, eight, racecar, madam, nine, refer, ten, 12345678987654321 $!?no comma";
    std::vector words = split(text);
    auto middle = stable_partition(begin(words), end(words), isPalindrome);
    sort(begin(words), middle, [](auto& word1, auto& word2){return word1.size() < word2.size();});
    std::cout << "----[ Palindromes ]----\n";
    for (auto& word: words) {
        std::cout << word << '\n';
        if (decltype(middle)(&word) == middle-1) std::cout << "----[ Non palindromes ]----\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Demo here: https://godbolt.org/z/7c69WP5Ph

Comment: I don't think it'll happen in this program but `idxRight{word.size()-1};` will not end well if `word.size() == 0`

Comment: Strangely I tested `isPalindrome("")` before posting and it didn't crash or take any longer...  but I agree a pre-check with `word.empty()` would be safer. It also raises the question, "is an empty string a palindrome?" Hmm...